# ¿Como puedo agregar el nombre de feriado en full calendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Necesito mostrar el `nombre` de un evento pero no se como aplicarlo en este caso, utilizo `fullcalendar` y quiero que me muestre el `nombre` de los feriados, actualmente con el `código` solo muestra el día con colores según sea dominical u opcional.

```
 renderHolidays(){
    this.holidays.forEach(element => {
      var formatDate = moment(element.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      if (element.timeZone === 'fullDay') {
        $("td[data-date=" + formatDate + "]").addClass('holiday2');
      }
      else {
        $("td[data-date=" + formatDate + "]").addClass('holiday');}
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que quieres hacer sólo debes pasar el nombre y la fecha en la configuración. Especificamente en `events`:

```
events:[{ title: 'Feriado', start: '2018-08-01' }]
```

Te adjunto ejemplo completo:

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.7.0/fullcalendar.css">
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.7.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    events:[
     {
            title: 'Nombre Feriado',
            start: '2018-08-01'
        }
    ]    
  })
</script>
```

Saludos colega!

Comment: eso no me estaria funcionando, se me cae todo el calendario en el front.

Comment: probablemente estes usando una versión diferente de fullCalendar... que te indica la consola de Chrome?

Comment: ya lo solucione, simplemente agregue otro render que muestra el nombre de los feriados